# Using cut with unprintable delimiters

Tags: linux, command-line

Is it possible to use cut and have unprintable characters be the delimiter? For example I'd like to have the "^A" characters (also represented as \001) be the delimiter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you're using Bash,

```
cut -d $'\001' ...
```

works (see [Bash Reference Manual # 3.1.2.4 ANSI-C Quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting)).

Other (more portable) options,

```
cut -d `echo -e '\001'` ...

FS=`echo -e '\001'`
cut -d $FS ...
```

or inserting the control character directly using ^V as mentioned by Alnitak and etlerant -- on the shell command line, and in editors such as vi, this means "don't treat the next thing I type specially".

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it's perfectly possible.

If typing in a shell, press `^V` and then `^A` to insert the `^A` verbatim in the current line rather than have it treated as the normal 'go to start of line' command:

```
% cat -v foo
abc^Adef^Aghi
% cut -d^A -f2 foo
def
```

Answer (score 1):

If for example you unprintable delimiter is `tab` which is equivalent of `\t` and you want to find the second to the end item of each line separated by tab you can use this:

```
cut -d $'\t' -f2- tablimited.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

CTRL-V CTRL-A ?